# Positioning the label of a checkbox in a fieldset

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox, fieldset

I have a registration form and used `fieldset` to order the `input` fields in two rows.

Now I need to add a checkbox below them. Sure, I could do so with a `div`, but I want to integrate it into the `fieldset`.

[Here is an example fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7hMCN/)

I need to add a checkbox under the last list item (the one with class `fd`) and **beside** that, the label for it.

At the end, it should look like this:

```
   label 1                         label 2
    _______________                 _______________ 
   (_______________)               (_______________)

    label 3                        label 4
    _______________                 _______________ 
   (_______________)               (_______________)


   (_) label 5
```

At this point I have the following code:

```
...
<li class="fd">
<label class ="tandc">label 5</label>
  <input class="tac"type="checkbox" id="tandc" name="tandc" tabindex="30" autocomplete="off" />
</li>


</ul>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And as for the CSS:

```
.tc  {
    float: right;
}
.tac {
    width: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


.tandc {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #ECECEC;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 450px;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 25px;
    padding-top: 3px;

}
```

My problem is that I'm only able to get the label above the checkbox and not beside it. Can anyone tell me how to put the label next to the checkbox? It's okay to change my HTML, but please avoid using tables.

Comment: here is the example! http://jsfiddle.net/fFddz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what element is styled using the .tc class but I just moved the label after the checkbox and removed the `float:right` you had for class `.tandc` and it looks like what you're trying to explain.

may be this what you're looking for?

**EDIT**

**updated css**

```
.tandc {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bolder;
color: #ECECEC;
text-decoration: none;
width: 450px;
height: 30px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

**html**

```
....
<li class="fd">
<input class="tac"type="checkbox" id="tandc" name="tandc" tabindex="30" autocomplete="off" />
<label class ="tandc">label 5</label>
</li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Since you have specific class and id for this `<li>` element you should be able to position it however you want independently.

**EDIT**

After seeing your full css I noticed you've specified that every input field is displayed as block. That means that no other element can be on the same line as the input field, like the div elements (your checkbox being one of those input fields). What you need to do is specify that this particular input box can have other elements inline with it. You can just add to class .tandc or to id #tandc `display:inline-block`.

Comment: hello and thanks for answering. i have the problem that i can see the checkbox. beside of it with an distance of 5-10px down the  label is located. even when i try to recoordinate with margin and padding inside the tac class or tandc i can not center them to one height and one line. thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure where your problem is as it is perfectly aligned vertically in every browser I try it(I noticed you had styling for class .tc which didn't exist in the html you posted so may be posting your full form code would help) But take a look at this - [vertical-align property](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html)and then you can try it out in w3schools's label or form tag page.

Comment: my problem is just the checkbox below the input fields. i would like to have the checkbox and directly beside this on one height with the cb there should be the label for it. i dont know which browser you use, see the link i posted. in my ff and safari there is the same problem with that. is there something like jsfiddle for images? then i can make a snapshot to show what i mean, thanks.

Comment: i tried out. it is actually okay... still not perfect because of the following issue: i can see that the checkbox will be in a div-like container which measures i can not really find. this kind of positioning the label seems much difficulter than using just simple divs. there i can change nearly everything into the right position. first thing i dont know how to change is the space between cb and label. the next thing is how to set the space to the upper input fields... so many questions left. thanks a lot.

Comment: to set the cb's properties specifically in your css you can use `.fd input.tac{}` to position the label with class `.tandc` you can use the `position:relative` property and adjust top and left. to reference your upper input fields you should use `.fl input` It's all about referencing the elements properly in your css